# WEBRTC + PEERJS - Stream from 2 cameras same time from one user

Tags: camera, java-stream, webrtc, p2p, peerjs

Hi I have currently web app where users can stream video from camera to each other, but I have question:
Is it possible to stream from 2 cameras same time from one user and send this two streams to another one ?

I'm using javascript with peer.js,node.js,socke.io and express.

Comment: Can you describe the languages you are using your use case?

Comment: Sorry for late response I'm using javascript with peer.js library

Comment: Hi guys... there is a solution for that? I need to create a product with these same technologies.